# Is there a script function that would pull up my network files and let me pick one to import?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm setting up a file comparison in google sheets. One file type is an excel sheet sent to my email on the first of every month. The other file type is a .txt file autosaved onto my computer in a shared network from an app I have, and that one is saved every hour on the hour. I need the user to be able to click the button connected to the script, and give them the file explorer so they can pick the proper file. Any file they would pick is in the same folder, they just have to pick the one with the timestamp they want.

The excel sheet is already auto-uploaded into the drive and auto-uploaded into the file comparison. I can't figure out how to give the user the option to select the second file they want to upload (the one coming from my shared network) with the push of a button, other than having them manually click "file, import, import from my computer..."

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.